# Set: in the part assignment is not a symbol

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm creating a cocktail sort function in mathmatica, but get a Set: in the part assignment is not a symbol.

Here is my code:

```
cocktailSort[A_List] := 
 Module[{swapped = True}, While[swapped == True, swapped = False;
    For[i = 1, i < Length[A] - 1, i++, 
     If[A[[i]] > A[[i + 1]], A[[i ;; i + 1]] = A[[i + 1 ;; i ;; -1]]; 
      swapped = True;]];
    If[swapped == False, Break[]];
    swapped = False;
    For[i = Length[A] - 1, i > 0, i--, 
     If[A[[i]] > A[[i + 1]], A[[i ;; i + 1]] = A[[i + 1 ;; i ;; -1]]; 
      swapped = True;]]] A]
cocktailSort[{2, 3, 1, 7, 5, 4}]
```

When I run this, I get the following error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jo24v.png)

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You are trying to assign values to an argument of a function and that isn't allowed. Try this `cocktailSort[vA_List] := Module[{swapped = True,A=vA},` followed by the rest of your code. That assigns the argument to a local variable which you are allowed to change and then runs your program with that local variable. That then correctly sorts your example list.